# How can I install specialized environments for different Perl applications?

Tags: python, perl, virtualenv

Is there anything equivalent or close in terms of functionality to Python's [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv#what-it-does), but for Perl?

I've done some development in Python and a possibility of having non-system versions of modules installed in a separate environment without creating any mess is a huge advantage. Now I have to work on a new project in Perl, and I'm looking for something like virtualenv, but for Perl. Can you suggest any Perl equivalent or replacement for python's virtualenv?

I'm trying to setup X different sets of non-system Perl packages for Y different applications to be deployed. Even worse, these applications may require different versions of the same package, so each of them may require to be installed in a separate module/library environment. You may want to do this manually for X < Y < 3. But you should not do this manually for 10 > Y > X.

Ideally what I'm looking should work like this:

```
perl virtualenv.pl my_environment
. my_environment/bin/activate
wget http://.../foo-0.1.tar.gz
tar -xzf foo-0.1.tar.gz ; cd foo-0.1
perl Makefile.pl
make install # <-- package foo-0.1 gets installed inside my_environment
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bar' # <-- now package Bar with all its deps gets installed inside my_environment
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to setup X different sets of non-system perl packages for Y different applications to be deployed. Even worse, these applications may require different versions of the same package, so each of them may require to be installed in separate module/library environment. 

You may want to do this manually for X < Y < 3. But you should not do this manually for 10 > Y > X. I was looking for a tool which would automate and simplify this, and it appears that local::lib is exactly that tool.

Comment: I don't think local::lib is what you are looking for. If you want each application on the same host to not share anything, it isn't going to handle that for you without a lot of work.

Comment: Well, you may think whatever you are used to, but it already does. Please notice that I was not looking for something that prevents any sharing, but I was looking for something to not share the non-system perl modules in an easy way, and local::lib does exactly that kind of thing.

Comment: Brian: I'm curious what you mean, because that's exactly what it's meant to do. With the `--self-contained` option it even removes system directories from the search path (so that you don't unknowingly depend on system-wide modules, and making your apps more portable).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's a tool called [`local::lib`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/local::lib) that wraps up all of the work for you, much like `virtualenv`. It will:

- Set up `@INC` in the process where it's used.
- Set `PERL5LIB` and other such things for child processes.
- Set the right variables to convince CPAN, [`MakeMaker`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/ExtUtils::MakeMaker), [`Module::Build`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Module::Build), etc. to install libraries and store configuration in a local directory.
- Set `PATH` so that installed binaries can be found.
- Print environment variables to stdout when used from the commandline so that you can put `eval $(perl -Mlocal::lib)`
  in your `.profile` and then mostly forget about it.

Answer (score 3):

Also checkout [perl-virtualenv](https://github.com/jizhang/perl-virtualenv) , this seems to be wrapper around local::lib as suggested by Hobbs, but creates a bin/activate and bin/deactivate so you can use it just like the python tool.

I've been using it quite successfully for a month or so without realising it wasn't as standards as perhaps it should be.

It makes it lot easier to set up a working virtualenv for perl as while local:lib  will tell you what variables you need to set, etc. perl-virtualenv creates an activate script which does it for you.

Answer (score 2):

I've used `schroot` for this purpose.  It is a bit heavier than virtualenv but you can be sure that nothing will leak in that shouldn't.

`Schroot` manages a chroot environment for you, but mounts your home directory in the chroot so it appears like a normal shell session, just using the binaries and libraries in the chroot.

I think it may be debian/ubuntu only though.

After setting up the `schroot`, your script above would look like

```
schroot -c my_perl_dev
wget ...
```

See http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/566 for an interesting article about it

Answer (score 2):

While investigating, I discovered this and some other pages ([this one is too old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950300/what-is-the-relationship-between-virtualenv-and-pyenv) and misses new technologies, [this reddit post is a slight misdirect](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/3hry19/how_do_you_make_something_similar_to_a_python/)).

The problem with perlbrew and plenv is that they seem to be replacements for pyenv, not virtualenv. As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950300/what-is-the-relationship-between-virtualenv-and-pyenv) pyenv is for managing python versions, virtualenv is for managing per-project module versions. So, yes, in some ways similar to [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/~haarg/local-lib-2.000019/lib/local/lib.pm#CREATING_A_SELF-CONTAINED_SET_OF_MODULES), but with better usability.

I've not seen a proper answer to this question yet, but from what I've read, it looks like the best solution is something along the lines of:

- Perl version management: [plenv](https://github.com/tokuhirom/plenv)/[perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) (with most people
  favouring the more contemporary bash based plenv over the perl based
  perlbrew from what I can see)
- Module version management: [Carton](https://github.com/perl-carton/carton)
- Module installation: cpan (well, [cpanminus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861292/which-cpan-installer-is-the-right-one-cpan-pm-cpanplus-cpanminus) anyway, ymmv)

To be honest, this is not an *ideal* set up, although I'm still learning, so it may yet be superior. It just doesn't feel right. It certainly isn't a like for like replacement for [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/).

There are a couple of posts I've found saying "[it](http://blog.polettix.it/parachuting-perl/) [is](http://www.slideshare.net/pplusdomain/plenv-and-carton) [possible](http://kappataumu.com/articles/modern-perl-toolchain-for-web-apps.html)" but neither has gone any further.

Answer (score 1):

Programs can modify what directories they check for libraries uwith [`use lib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html).  This lib directory can be relative to the current directory.  Libraries from these directories will be used before system libraries, as they are placed at the beginning of the @INC array.

I believe cpan can also install libraries to specific directories.  Granted, cpan draws from the [CPAN site](http://www.cpan.org/) in order to install things, so this may not be the best option.

Comment: `@LIB` doesn't do anything. ITYM `@INC`

Comment: I know about these options. Yes, I know, I can write some simple scripts to initialize environment and directory structure, I can even convince CPAN to use that directory structure, and I can do many other interesting things. But I need to do this manually. 

One of the key features of virtualenv is that 'without creating any mess' part. It hides all these low-level setup steps away and greatly simplifies using such environments. I'm looking for something similar for Perl. I simply can't believe it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this is the same as that `virtualenv` thing you are talking about, but have a look for the `@INC` special variable in the `perlvar` manpage.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need to use the INSTALL_BASE configuration for Makefile.PL (or the --install_base option for Build.PL)? What exactly do you need the solution to do for you? It sounds like you just need to get the installed module in the right place. You've presented your problem as an [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341) by specifying what you think is the solution is rather than letting us help you with your task.

See [How do I keep my own module/library directory?](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How_do_I_keep_my_own) in perlfaq8, for instance.

If you are downloading modules from CPAN, the latest `cpan` command (in [App::Cpan](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-Cpan)) has a `-j` switch to allow you to choose alternate CPAN.pm configuration files. In those configuration files you can set the CPAN.pm options to install wherever you like.

Based on your clarification, it sounds like local::lib might work for you in single, simple cases, but I do this for industrial strength deployments where I set up custom, private CPANs per application, and install directly from those custom CPANs. See my [MyCPAN::App::DPAN](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MyCPAN-App-DPAN) module, for instance. From that, I use custom CPAN.pm configs that analyze their environment and set the proper values to each application can install everything in a directory just for that application.

You might also consider distributing your application as a Task::. You install it like any other Perl module, but dependencies share that same setup (i.e. INSTALL_BASE).

Comment: I know about all this stuff, but it is quite low-level. I wanted a tool which can quickly make all these low-level setup/configuration steps for me with just a simple command. I know that I've presented this as an XY Problem, but if you check the accepted answer then you will find that it works almost exactly as I've described. You should try that solution yourself if you haven't done yet.

Comment: I don't see how it works for you if you want to install more than 10 different setups on the same machine, as you say in the comment to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is start the CPAN shell (cpan) and install my own Perl 5.10 from it
(I believe the command is install perl-5.10).  This will ask for various configuration
settings; I make sure to make it point to paths under /usr/local
(or some other installation location other than the default).

Then I put its resulting location in my executable $PATH before the standard perl, and use its CPAN shell to install the modules I need (usually, a lot).
My Perl scripts all start with the line

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

Never had a problem with this approach.

Comment: Installing your own Perl is not in option if you need 5-10 different environments.

Comment: You mean it isn't fully automated?  Yes, that's a drawback.  I'm sure it would be easy to automate (just a matter of figuring out how to provide config choices to the Perl installation), but I never did that.

Comment: BTW I always install software in a version-specific subdirectory, then use something like stow to symlink one version into a location that's in my path.  That way I can still use specific versions when needed.

Comment: I mean that it does not work fine when you want to stay with system perl, while using customized non-system set of modules. You will need this when you are deploying an application.

Comment: True: not staying with the system's perl doesn't work if you want to stay with the system's perl.  There may be legitimate reasons why you'd want to do that; my point is that I haven't met any in practice, and I use Perl quite a lot.