# Workflow to debug for a Perl programmer

Tags: perl, debugging

I am new to `Perl` and I have the following problem.
I have a log output and I have found where this log output comes from. I mean the subroutine in some module that prints it.

Now e.g. in `Java` via `Eclipse` I would use e.g. `Call hierarchy` and other utilities to see how/when/who calls the method and figure out how to reproduce what I need and debug.

How can I do this in `Perl`? Via e.g. `grep`? If I `grep` e.g. for the module name I get hundrends of lines ranging from `use A` `require A` `C::B::A` `B::A` `C::B::A::some_routine` `C::B::A::some_other_routine` etc.
On top of this I am worried that perhaps the routine I am interested in is not called directly but some script e.g. runs the module that is of interest to me via some obscure (to me due to my ignorance in `Perl`) manner.

So how would I go debug something in `Perl` in the most efficient way? What do you `Perl` gurus suggest for me to do and become more efficient?

Comment: If you have the EPIC IDE for Eclipse then you can set a breakpoint in the subroutine in the usual way. You can see the call stack from there once the program is paused.

Answer (score 5):

Run the program under the Perl debugger:

```
perl -d scriptname arguments...
```

Set a breakpoint in the function you care about, and when the program stops at the breakpoint use the `T` debugger command to display a stack trace, which will show where the function was called from.

From your comments, I'm not sure this actually addresses what you're looking for. Maybe what you want is a cross-reference of the Perl application? See the FAQ [How do I cross-reference my Perl programs?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq3.html#How-do-I-cross-reference-my-Perl-programs?)

Comment: +1. I don't know where the program starts. I mean there is no `main` like in `Java` or `C++`. From my (ignorant) perspective I have many scripts that could call the module and I don't really know what the flow is.Does what I am saying make sense?

Comment: Perl programs are scripts, so they start with the top-level code that isn't in any function definitions.

Comment: Does the `perl -d` require a graphical environment?

Comment: So you recommend to run the script as a program under a debugger? Ok. But how can I also find out which other modules call routine of this module?

Comment: You have to know the main script that is being run in the application. You run that script with the `-d` option, set a breakpoint in the module you care about. Then wait for the breakpoint to be hit, do a stack trace, and you'll see the function in some other module that called it.

Comment: Well. That is my main problem I don't know the main script.It is a large script repository

Comment: +1 for the FAQ link and [B::Xref](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Xref.html). I wouldn't recommend debugger as *first* option though.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time getting a stack trace (along with some debugging info) is a good start. One can use standard [Carp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Carp) module to generate stack traces:

```
use Carp;  
print_to_log(Carp::longmess("We're here"));
```

Or there's an [object-oriented module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3A%3AStackTrace) for that as well.

Comment: So you mean modify the script to add the `Carp`?

Comment: Not the script, but the module containing the function of interest.

Answer (score 4):

To get a dump of the call stack without modifying any code, you can use the perl command line to run your program under [Carp::Always](https://metacpan.org/module/Carp%3a%3aAlways):

```
perl -MCarp::Always my_program.pl
```

Comment: I get `Can't locate Carp/Always.pm in @INC `

Comment: @Cratylus you might need to install the module from CPAN then, see `man cpan` (I guess it comes with Perl) or [cpanminus](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App%3A%3Acpanminus‎). See also [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861292/which-cpan-installer-is-the-right-one-cpan-pm-cpanplus-cpanminus)