# How to exit current CPAN module and open a new session?

Tags: perl, ubuntu, package, dbi, cpan

I am new to perl and CPAN. I see that perl is installed in my system.

However, I would like to install `DBI` package to run a script called `INSTALL.PL`.

When I type `CPAN`, I get the below error message

```
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
Terminal does not support AddHistory.

There seems to be running another CPAN process (pid 3986).  Contacting...
Other job not responding. Shall I overwrite the lockfile '/home/abcd/.cpan/.lock'? (Y/n) [y]
```

If I give `no`, I don't get the `CPAN` command prompt. Whereas if I give `yes`, I get the below command prompt

`nolockcpan[1]`

May I know what does the error message mean and what are the steps to follow to avoid this message again?

Can't I enter into `cpan` mode and press `CTRL+Z` exit and again get into `cpan` mode?

How can I avoid this error message and when can this happen?

Comment: Re "*May I know what does the error message mean*", It means it didn't exit cleanly the last time you used it.

Comment: Re "*Can't I enter into cpan mode and press CTRL+Z exit and again get into cpan mode?*", Yes, by entering `fg` as normal.

Comment: @ikegami - May I know how can I exit cpan mode? When I type `fg` in the cpan prompt, I get the below message `Unknown shell command 'fg'. Type ? for help.`

Comment: `exit` or `quit`, can't remember which. Ctrl-D surely also works. /// `fg` is the *shell* command to get back *into* `cpan` after suspending it using Ctrl-Z

Comment: Sure, thanks. You can write as an answer and I can accept it.

Comment: FWIW, I install packages from [CPAN](https://www.cpan.org/) by running `cpanm -i PackageName` on the command line.  That uses [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpanminus/bin/cpanm), which is much simpler than [cpan](https://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html). I find a good summary of differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5861292/4653379), and also see a note on the `cpan` page itself. The `cpanm` need be installed, with `curl -L https://cpanmin.us | perl - --sudo App::cpanminus` for instance (taken from [App::cpanminus](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus)).

Comment: @zdim, `cpan -i PackageName` works just as well with `cpan`. The lock is only used when using the shell. // The only benefit listed on the linked page is that `cpanm` uses less memory, which isn't relevant here.

Comment: @ikegami Sure, my "fwiw" comment doesn't address their issue here, true. I was commenting more in general, as they seem unaware of `cpanm`.  (Its advantage is also that there is no configuration to deal with, literally install and use, with all "instructions" in that one comment. But then of course a disadvantage may be that one can't configure and tweak it as one can with `cpan`.)  It's good to know for such an option.

Comment: @zdim, Re "*Its advantage is also that there is no configuration to deal with*", My point is that this is true for `cpan` too. You don't have to deal with configuring `cpan` either. By default, it "just works" like `cpanm`. (Note that some aspects of the build process can be configured even when using `cpanm`. You just have to use env vars to do it. But that's the preferred way for `cpan` too.)

Comment: @ikegami Right, good point -- my experiences with `cpan` (kinda long ago by now) were always more verbose and involved more work, and I forgot that that isn't _necessary_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that `cpan` wasn't properly exited the last time it was run. This could happen if you close your terminal while it's still running, for example.

You can use `exit` or `quit` to exit `cpan`. It will also exit when its STDIN reaches EOF (which can be done using Ctrl-D on unix).

You talk of Ctrl-Z, which stops (suspends) it, but doesn't exit it. Use `fg` to return to `cpan` after stopping it. That said, launching `cpan` while it's stopped or otherwise still running results in a different message (`Other job is running. Shall I try to run in downgraded mode?`).